Cant open files in git repository, error: the following files were specified on the command line these files could not be found and will not be loaded
There were files that I wanted to upload to my git repository via soucetree but I got an error while staging, "file name too long". Then I found a solution online 'git config "--global" core.longpaths true', afterwards I could stage, commit and push them. And I asked all my team members to use this command as well, and after they did, they could pull all those files.
However, now that the files are in the repository, I cannot open the files, I get the error: The following files were specified on the command line, these files could not be found and will not be loaded. Note: If I try to open them as a text file via Notepad, it works fine. I can see the code. But not with my editor.
Solutions that I have tried, that didn't work:

Made sure that SourceTree is using the System’s Git and not the embedded one. Tools > Options > Git > Use System Git

Add the line:
longpaths = true
to my .gitconfig file under the "core" section.



How long are these filenames?
